# Get span value inside nested div and other HTML element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to get span value which is inside h1> a> span tag so those span value I want to get but when my jQuery code  is getting empty values, unable to figure out what I  have missed.

```js
$(".main_content .wpb_wrapper").each((i, elem) => {

  console.log('test::' + $(elem).find(".wpb_content_element >a >span").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="main_content">
  1)

  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <h3 style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://abc/"><span style="color: #405789;">abc Estates</span></a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

2)

<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <h3 style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://xyz/"><span style="color: #405789;">xyz Estates</span></a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

3)

<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <h3 style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://mm/"><span style="color: #405789;">mm Estates</span></a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `a` is not a *direct* descendent (/ immediate child) of `.wpb_content_element` - so `.wpb_content_element > a` finds nothing - either add the intervening `h3` or doesn't use the immediate child `>` instruction.   `$(elem).find(".wpb_content_element a > span").text()` / `$(elem).find(".wpb_content_element > h3 > a > span").text()`

Comment: @freedomn-m  I used your solution from comment , still getting empty.

Comment: You also have an extra `</div>` after your first `wpb_text_column` so there's only 1 `wpb_wrapper` inside `main_content`

Comment: Look at the hierarchy of your elements for the first wrapper (as you only have 1 inside main_content, that's the only relevant one):   `main_content > wpb_content_element > wpb_wrapper > h3 > a > span` - you're looking for `element` *inside* `wrapper` - but that's not how your html is laid out.

Comment: It also turns out you have wpb_wrapper *inside* wpb_wrapper, so that won't help either.   Probably want to sort out your html in the first instance.

Comment: On review, the extra `</div>` is probably because there's a missing `<div class="wpb_wrapper">` around the first `wpb_content_element` rather than an extra `</div>`

Comment: Best guess at fixing your html: https://jsfiddle.net/yntsokuz/